# WPF RoutedCommand CanExecute event is not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command

I have created a UserControl that has a command (DeleteCommand) inside:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public static RoutedCommand DeleteCommand = new RoutedCommand();
    private void DeleteCommandExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void DeleteCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }



    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CommandBinding deleteCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(DeleteCommand, DeleteCommandExecute, DeleteCommandCanExecute);
            this.CommandBindings.Add(deleteCommandBinding);
    }
}
```

I have put this UserControl inside a Window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestRoutedCommand.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestRoutedCommand"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Fire event" Margin="156,29,205,254" Command="{x:Static local:TestControl.DeleteCommand}" />        
        <local:TestControl Margin="126,135,135,46"/>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There is also a Button which is using the DeleteCommand. My problem is that this button is always disabled and the DeleteCommandCanExecute handler is never called, although e.CanExecute is always set to true.

I have tried to call:

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

but nothing happens. The event is never fired. Maybe I am doing the CommandBinding wrong.

What I want to achieve is that when the user clicks on the button that the DeleteCommandExecute handler is fired. My goal is to create commands for my MenuButtons which will trigger some methods in my UserControls which can be deep in the Visual Tree.

Comment: If your command is static, have you tried switching DeleteCommandExecute and DeleteCommandCanExecute to static as well?

Comment: Try making DeleteCommand a property instead of just a member variable?

Comment: Why is there a command in a UserControl? You would typically have a command in a view model, where you use a helper class like [RelayCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) for its implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly change your XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Fire event" Margin="156,29,205,254" Command="{x:Static local:TestControl.DeleteCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=Control1}" />        
    <local:TestControl x:Name="Control1" Margin="126,135,135,46"/>        
</Grid>
```

CommandTarget says where to find needed handlers.

Comment: Yes, but I have to fire the Execute in the UserControl. Your solution is equal to a Click EventHandler that is bound to the button

Comment: Ok, i'll change the solution

Comment: But what if the UserControl is deeper in the Visual Tree? Lets say, a UserControl inside a UserControl, and that Child UserControl needs to fire the Execute event

Comment: You just need link to control. It can be in .cs code (property): `button.Command = TestControl.DeleteCommand;` `button.CommandTarget=link;` It depends from the situation, but find you control in visual tree will also work.